# Test "wall wart" power supply

Tags: power-supply, multimeter, dummy-load

I am purchasing a 3 ampere USB A power supply (5V.)  What would be the easiest way to apply a known load from 0-3 amperes (in 0.5 ampere increments, for example) so that I could connect a multimeter and see how close the supply is to 5V at each of those loads?

Comment: A bunch of ten ohm power resistors.  But while voltage sag is interesting, the things that are really important to know aren't necessarily things you can find out in a quick test with a simple meter as your instrument.

Comment: @ChrisStratton could you elaborate on the other items that would be interesting to know?